# How to serialize child as parent object in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization

I have a common TransfertObject who need to be serialized between server and client.
The DatabaseObject has the same field + some db specific fields and some annotations but is known only by the server side.
I made the DatabaseObject extends the TransfertObject, but when I serialize it, I can't deserialize on the client it because *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException* on the DatabaseObject.
How can I serialize my DatabaseObject as a TransfertObject ?

```
public class TransfertObject implements Serializable {
   private String transferredProperties;
}

public class DatabaseObject extends TransfertObject {
   private String dbProperties;
}
```

I know I can make dbProperties *transient* but that doesn't resolve the *ClassNotFoundException*

So far the only workaround I found was to copy properties from one object to the other before serializing it.

```
public TransfertObject asTransfertObject(DatabaseObject dbObj) {
    TransfertObject transObj = new TransfertObject();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(dbObj, transObj);
    return transObj;
}
```

I think could also do the same with the *writeReplace* method

```
public class DatabaseObject extends TransfertObject {
   private String dbProperties;

   private Object writeReplace() throws ObjectStreamException {
      TransfertObject transObj = new TransfertObject();
      transObj.transferredProperties = this.transferredProperties;
      // copy other properties
      return transObj;
   }
}
```

But that doesn't remove the burden of copying every parent properties.

Isn't there a way to "more than cast" my object for serialization ?

Comment: I think you can simply cast `(TransferObject) databaseObjectInstance ` before serialize it, then without deep copy

Comment: No, simple cast doesnt do the job, it's always the "real" object who is serialized.
Consider a `Parent` not serializable and a `Child` who is, it's because `Child` is an `instanceof Serializable` that it can be serialized even when casted as `Parent`.

Comment: You also can't serialize an interface but your instance can be cast into one. What I'm looking for is a way to "more than cast", strip the child aspect of my instance, if possible.